# Strange POSTs in my Apache access log

Tags: apache, post

My Apache server has been overloading and I'm trying to trouble shoot why.
In looking into the apache access log I see tons of entries like this:

```
POST /?CtrlFunc_999999AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA HTTP/1.0
POST /?CtrlFunc_ppppqqqqqqqrrrrrrrsssssssstttt HTTP/1.0
POST /?CtrlFunc_KOUZdilsx27BGKOSXbfkpv05AGKPTX HTTP/1.0
POST /?CtrlFunc_rrsssssstttttuuuuuvvvvvwwwwwwx HTTP/1.0
```

All from different IP addresses.  It seems strange that all these different IP's would all be sending sequential alpha-numeric requests.  Is this some type of encoding that I'm not familiar with?  I couldn't find out anything about the:

```
?CtrlFunc
```

either.  There are hundreds of entries like this coming from IP addresses in China, Taiwan, India, Equador, and Spain to name a few.
Is this normal behavior?  I'm just trying to track down why my apache server gets overloaded every time I turn it on.  Maybe there's a more efficient way to look at the server processes, but I haven't found it.

Comment: try googling `POST /?CtrlFunc_`.. you'll find something useful [yeah i went through results] some one else has this problem as well.. probably it's a botnet scouring the web for entry points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen the same attack.

The people over at the Internet Storm Center do not have a method for stopping the flow, but have some suggestions on how to drop the incoming requests:

https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Defending+Against+Web+Server+Denial+of+Service+Attacks/16240

Particularly Comment #2, from the Mod_Security team member, which seems to work well for me.

Comment: Thanks this was a great solution.  I was able to use Mod_security and mod_evasive to filter out the post calls in question.  However I think there were so many calls that those modules were then overloading the server. I set up CloudFlare, and between that and the apache modules I back in reasonable operating range.